# Ajax PHP Jquery HoverCard Positioning

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css

[image]

Hello friends.
This is **[DEMO](http://www.ecowebtr.com/f/)** page

As you can see in the picture when i hover page top user1 then hovercard working normal. But if i scroll down to hover user5 or user6 then hovercard not shown next to the username it slips up like in image.

I'm using the following jQuery code for the positioning.

```js
function showProfileTooltip(e, id){
   var top = e.clientY + 20;
   var left = e.clientX - 10;

   $('.p-tooltip').css({
    'top':top,
    'left':left
   }).show();
   //send id & get info from get_profile.php
   $.ajax({
    url: 'get_profile.php?uid='+id,
    beforeSend: function(){
     $('.p-tooltip').html('Loading..');
    },
    success: function(html){
     $('.p-tooltip').html(html);
    }
   });
  }

  function hideProfileTooltip(){
   $('.p-tooltip').hide();
  }

  $('.profile').mouseover(function(e){
   var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
   showProfileTooltip(e, id);
  });

  $('.p-tooltip').mouseleave(function(){
   hideProfileTooltip();
  });
 });
```

```css
.p-tooltip{
  background: #fafbfb;
border: 1px solid #BFBFBF;
width: 320px;
margin: 0 auto;
border-radius: 5px;
position: absolute;
display: none;
padding: 0 0 10px 0;
 }
 .p-tooltip-cover img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
 }
 .p-tooltip-avatar{
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: -45px;
  margin-left: 10px;
 }
 .p-tooltip-avatar img{
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
  padding: 4px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
 }
 .p-tooltip-info{
  text-align: left;
 }
 .p-tooltip-info .p-username{
float: none;
margin-top: -70px;
margin-left: 100px;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
color: white;
 }
 .p-tooltip-info .p-headline{
  float: none;
margin-top: 6px;
margin-left: 100px;
font-size: 12px;
color: black;
 }
 .p-tooltip-button{
  float: right;
  margin-top: 5px;
 }
 .p-tooltip-button button{
  cursor: pointer;
 }
```

```html
<div class="p-tooltip"></div>
<table cellpadding="20">
<td><a href="#" class="profile" data-id="25">user1</a></td>
  <tr>
  <td><a href="#" class="profile" data-id="26">user2</a></td>
  <tr>
  <td><a href="#" class="profile" data-id="27">user3</a></td>
  <tr>
  <td><a href="#" class="profile" data-id="28">user4</a></td>
  <tr>
  <td><a href="#" class="profile" data-id="29">user5</a></td>
  <tr>
  <td><a href="#" class="profile" data-id="30">user6</a></td>
  <tr>
  <td><a href="#" class="profile" data-id="31">user7</a></td>
  <tr>
  <td><a href="#" class="profile" data-id="32">user8</a></td>
  <tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using `.e.clientY` and `e.clientX` to locate the position of the element, you can simply use `.position()`

In the `mouseover` event pass in `$(this)` to the `showProfileTooltip` function instead of the event (`e`):

```
$('.profile').mouseover(function(e){
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    showProfileTooltip($(this), id); //pass '$(this)' instead
});
```

Then in the `showProfileTooltip` function you can find the top and left by using:

```
var top = e.position().top;
var left = e.position().left+50; //add whatever number you want to offset the positioning
```